# How to get the hash value from check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, hash

I want to get the value "0" (not checked) or "1" (checked) from check_box and save it as hash value.
But no value can be saved... paper: nil
I created the column "paper" as integer.
Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

View:

```
<div class="formgroup">
  <%= f.label :paper, "Paper_Collection" %>
  <% @paper.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="checkbox" >
    <%= f.check_box :paper, {checked: false, multiple: true}, value == "1" ? "checked" : "" %><%= key %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @box = Box.new
  @paper = {red: 0, blue: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0, black: 0, white: 0}
....
end
def create
  @box = Box.new(box_params)
  @box.user_id = current_user.id
  @paper = {red: 0, blue: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0, black: 0, white: 0}
...
end
private
 def box_params
  params.require(:box).permit(:status, :paper, :cable, reports: [])
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to get, and how you want to store that hash as an integer in the table but:

```
def new
  @box = Box.new
  @paper = {red: 0, blue: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0, black: 0, white: 0}
....
end
```

and in form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :paper do |paper_fields| %>
  <div class="formgroup">
    <%= paper_fields.label :paper, "Paper_Collection" %>
      <% @paper.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="checkbox" >
          <%= paper_fields.label key %>
          <%= paper_fields.check_box key, checked: value == 1 %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

should give you params like:

```
{ "box" => { "paper" => { "red" => "0", "blue"=>"0", "yellow"=>"1", ... } } }
```

so I guess its what yo're looking for

Comment: Thanks! However with above code, no check_box and key is showing.

Comment: I added `<%= paper_fields.label key %>` to answer. what about now? And `<%= f.fields_for :paper do |paper_fields| %>` sorry for that mistakes